# Define custom django template tag on the fly

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way in django to declare a custom template tag "on the fly"?

For example, if I have a page that renders an a tree structure and for my tag to work, it needs the root and the leaf. Since I now that I will use this tag **only** with this root (on the page), is there a way to create the template once I know which root will be used?

In my templates, I currently use:

```
{% render_leaf root leaf %}
```

I would like to create the tag "on the fly" (just after fetching the root), so that the root is now a local variable of the tag function, and I can simply call: `{% render_leaf leaf %}`

Comment: Can you not just do this in your view and make root dynamic based on some logic? Django also has an extensive set of render methods https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/template-response/

Comment: Actually I could create a partial template which writes `{% render_leaf root leaf %}` and then I just need to include it (root being globally defined in my template) with the correct `leaf` variable

Comment: Maybe helpfull: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: @allcaps thank, I knew about it^^

Answer (score 1):

It would be far easier to move the dynamic part of the solution into your view (as mentioned in comments), and pass the correct root and leaves in the template's context. Doing this should then make the template really straight forward.

Comment: I currently use `{% render_leaf root leaf %}` in my views, what would it be with your solution?

Comment: @oliverpool can you add your template code to the original question? It'll be easier to answer with code.

Comment: I edited the question, but `{% render_leaf root leaf %}` is really the only relevant part

Comment: The more I think about it, the less I actually want to add some "magic" to my tag: I will probably go on with `{% render_leaf root leaf %}`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone needs it, it's actually quite simple if you look at the source for Django's own `{% load %}` tag:

### Approach

1. define a static tag, e.g. `{% import_dynamic_tags %}`
2. the parser function for this tag gives you access to the `parser` instance, which offers an `add_library()` method
3. the argument for `add_library` is simply a new instance of `django.template.base.Library`
4. at the new instance of `Library`, just call `tag()` or `filter()` to create dynamic templatetags and filters

### Example

This code must be placed inside a regular template library, e.g. `myapp.templatetags.dynamic_tags`:

```py
from django.template.base import Node, Library

register = template.Library()

class DummyNode(Node):
    """ 
    empty DummyNode, required since a parser function 
    must return a Node instance 
    """
    def render(self, context):
        return ''

@register.tag
def import_dynamic_tags(parser, token):
    # create a new template library
    lib = Library()

    # create an "uppercase" filter dynamically. Library.filter() 
    # expects a name, a filter function and optional flags like takes_context
    lib.filter('uppercase', lambda x: x.upper(), )

    # create a custom "{% foo %}"  templatetag. Library.tag() 
    # expects a name and a compiler function (the function you would normally
    # decorate with @register_tag)
    lib.tag('foo', foo_func)

    # finally, tell the parser about our newly created library 
    parser.add_library(lib)

    # filter functions MUST return a node, so just return DummyNode which
    # does nothing at render time
    return DummyNode()
```